# How to get Docker container status and fail the pipeline if contianer not running

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have a Azure Pipeline to Build and deploy the Docker image.

Once deploy we need to check the deployed docker container status and fail the pipeline if contianer is not running.

We setup a yaml pipeline to build and deploy the Docker image which successfully deployed and contianer is running fine.

But we need to add a logic to get the contianer status if not running mark the pipeline as failed.

We used the below command to check the status.

sudo docker container ls --filter "name=$(module)" --filter "status=running"

Comment: Hi, which task are you using to run your docker container. It would be also nice if you share the `yml` file and `Dockerfile` so that the people reading your question will have something as a reference and can use that to implement the solution on top of it :)

Comment: Please find the docker and yaml file as below,                                                      
Docker file:

FROM custom-base-image

COPY ./test.war /ROOT.war
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]

Pipeline Yaml:

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |

      sudo docker run -itd --name Test -p 8080:8080 testimage:v$(Build.Buildnumber)
 sleep 30
      sudo docker container ls --filter "name=Test" --filter "status=running" | exit 1 --> This line is still commented out

Comment: Please let me know in which azure service you are deploying the docker container. Webapp or Function app or ACI or any other?

Comment: Its, development infra, where we are deploying to local RHEL 8.0 Server for now.

Comment: @SundarM Thanks for sharing the details. However, it will be easy for other to read if you update these details in your question by editing it. Use code blocks wherever necessary to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have tried to reproduce the same in my lab environment and got positive results after following the below steps.**

**Step 1:** Add the below code snippet to the pipeline which causes the pipeline to fail if the container is not running.

```
- script: |
   if docker ps | grep busy_wiles; then
      echo 'Container is running'
    else
      echo 'Container is not running'
      exit 1
    fi
```

****Note: In the above code ‘busy_wiles’ is my container name.***

**Step 2:** Run the pipeline and see the result.

•   Below is the output when the container is running.

[image]

•   Below is the output when the container is not running.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I couldn't upvote the answer.